# Remove year from date data type

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to build a custom sign up policy that will capture a few pieces of data from the user then verify it against a custom API we are building.

One of the pieces of data I need to verify is date of birth however I need to ask for only the Month and Day and NOT the year.

Using the built in datatype of date in the custom policy gives me a date picker but it includes the year.

```
<ClaimType Id="extension_dateOfBirth">
     <DisplayName>Date of Birth</DisplayName>
     <DataType>date</DataType>
     <AdminHelpText>Your date of birth.</AdminHelpText>
     <UserHelpText>Your date of birth.</UserHelpText>
     <UserInputType>DateTimeDropdown</UserInputType>
</ClaimType>
```

[image]

Is there anyway to capture just the month and day from the user and NOT the year?

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is just to have a string with a predicate for "dd/mm" or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing here is just using two input drop downs capturing ints, one for day and one for month.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).